# Why does a call to an ASP.NET MVC Controller not execute a DelegatingHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

**Introduce the Question**

I have recently learned that a call to an `ApiController` Action will trigger a `DelegatingHandler`'s `SendAsync` method, and that a call to a vanilla `Controller` Action will not trigger it.

**Search and Research**

I have looked into Web Api, and learned that it includes the `HttpMessageHandler`, which is the parent of the `DelegatingHandler` class. That leads me to believe that HTTP Message Handlers, in general, only execute as part of a Web API pipeline.

Also, [Http Message Handlers run before Url Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers), so it probably isn't URL routing that chooses between the Web API and MVC pipeline.

> ...consider using an action filter instead of a message handler [because a]ction filters
>   run after URI routing is performed.

**Question**

- Are `HttpMessageHandlers` a part of ASP.NET Web API but not of ASP.NET MVC?
- What is the `HttpMessageHandler` equivalent in MVC (**EQUIVALENT** in the diagram)?
- What causes the request to follow the Web API pipeline (**FORK** in the diagram)?
- Are Web API requests fundamentally different that MVC requests?

My sense is that it goes something like this, but please correct me.

```
               Request from Client
                       |
                      IIS
                       |                           
                    ASP.NET
                       |
            HttpApplication.BeginRequest
                       |
                   et cetera
                       |
         HttpApplication.MapRequestHandler - is this what does the routing?
                       |
                     FORK                           
                   /       \
                  /         \
                 /           \
                /             \
               /               \
         **Web API**           **MVC**
              |                   |
 HttpControllerRouteHandler   MvcRouteHandler
              |                   |
    HttpControllerHandler         |    
              |                   |
    HttpMessageHandlers       EQUIVALENT?
            i.e.                  |
    DelegatingHandlers            |
            incl.                 |
    HttpServer                    |
    CustomHandlers                |
    HttpRoutingDispatcher         |
    HttpControllerDispatcher      |
```

**Helpful Links**

[ASP.NET Application Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

[ASP.NET Web API Poster](http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster.pdf)

[Life Cycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](http://i2.asp.net/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Why does a call to a controller does not execute a delegating handler?

Well because they run down two different execution paths, if an MVC route matches it then executes an MVCHandler, while a delegating handler only executes when an Api route matches. In short the diagram above doesn't describe the split correctly.

Delegating handlers run AFTER routing and before action selection. The routing and action selection steps get often confused or used interchangeably although they are two distinct steps.

Routing is the step that matches a url to a set of string segments to produce the `RouteValues` which maps a route key to a route value. `RouteValues` is then used in action selection. The delegating handlers run in between these two steps.

There is no equivalent in MVC for delegating handlers, a similar way to do it is to write your own handler but you are getting in some deep water there, particularly with link generation.

Another simpler approach is to write a global filter, but note that it will only run if an action was actually selected.

### Line by line answers

#### Are HttpMessageHandlers a part of ASP.NET Web API but not of ASP.NET MVC?

Yes they are only WebAPI constructs.

#### What is the HttpMessageHandler equivalent in MVC (EQUIVALENT in the diagram)?

None really exist, and the diagram is wrong. The closest is a RouteHandler

#### What causes the request to follow the Web API pipeline (FORK in the diagram)?

Matching a WebAPI route

#### Are Web API requests fundamentally different that MVC requests?

No they are not, the fork happens only after routing.

#### EDIT (Aug-18-2015): In MVC Core, Web API was merged into MVC, and there is a single new pipeline.

Comment: Can you expand on the forking? Where does the match of an MVC vs Web Api route happen?

Comment: When you run on IIS (which is the default), routing happens in ASP.NET. Each route registers a "pattern" (or really a matching function) look at `Route` and `RouteBase` method `GetRouteData`, when the method returns value it means the route matches, and then the registered (per RouteBase object) IRouteHandler is invoked.

Comment: Here as some links:  
General asp.net routing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx
  IRouteHandler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler(v=vs.110).aspx  
Route class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.aspx

Comment: I didn't mark this as answer, because from reading [this](http://i2.asp.net/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf?version_id=&cdn_id=2014-05-05-001) and [this](http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster.pdf), it looks like `MvcHandler` is equivalent to `HttpControllerHandler`, and that the `HttpApplication.MapRequestHandler` chooses between them during not after routing.

Comment: Routing chooses a route, a route has a route handler. There are the two handlers like you mentioned, and that's why I'm saying that MvcHandler is NOT the same as a delegating handler, as a delegating handler gets inserted after the handler and can be chained.

Comment: I'm very close to marking your answer as answer. Could you please add a direct answer to the question that is in the title of the post.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work! You wrote: "In short the diagram above doesn't describe the split correctly." If you have the time, I would love your help in learning where it goes wrong and how to make it right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52151/discussion-between-yishai-galatzer-and-shaun-luttin)